# Sending data using <a href="#"> in the same page and display the result (FORM) using JSP without changing the (FORM) coding

Tags: java, forms, jsp, jstl, hashtag

```
<div id="main_search">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Product</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Bilateral-VC">Bilateral-VC
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Bilateral Non-VC">Bilateral Non-VC
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget Domestic">Budget Domestic
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget High">Budget High
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Budget International">Budget International
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="IDD Buffet Base">IDD Buffet Base
        <br>
        <input type="checkbox" name="product" class="prod_checkbx" value="Premium">Premium
        <br>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Destination</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td>
        <input id="destination" type="text" name="destination" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="9" align="center">
        <a id="search" name="search" class="button orange small" style="cursor:pointer" href="#">SEARCH</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="search_result" style="overflow: auto;">
  <h2>Floor Price Edit</h2>
  <table id="result-tbl" class="searchTable">
    <tr>
      <th>Destination</th>
      <th>Product</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <% String dest=r equest.getParameter( "destination"); %>
        <td>
          <%=d est %>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <% if (dest !=n ull) { %>
      <sql:setDataSource var="db" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/icars" user="root" password="" />
      <sql:query var="dest_result" dataSource="${dbsource}">
        SELECT * from icx_pricing_desk WHERE DESTINATION LIKE '
        <%=d est %>%'
      </sql:query>
      <c:forEach var="row" items="${dest_result.rows}">
        <tr>
          <td>
            <c:out value="${row.DESTINATION}" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </c:forEach>
      <% } %>
        <td>
          <% String products[]=r equest.getParameterValues( "product"); %>
            <% if(products !=n ull) { %>
              <% for(int i=0; i<products.length; i++) { %>
                <%=products[i]%>
                  <sql:query var="prod_result" dataSource="${db }">SELECT * FROM icx_pricing_desk WHERE PRODUCT = '
                    <%=products[i]%>'</sql:query>
                  <c:forEach var="row" items="${prod_result.rows}">
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <c:out value="${row.PRODUCT}" />
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </c:forEach>
                  <% } } %>
        </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

This is some kind of form without `<form>` tag and for submit button it didn't use `<input type="submit">` like normal form. It use `<a href="#">` to submit the data.

The question is how do you send the data using the `<a href="#">`???

In addition, when i click the `SEARCH` button both `<% String dest = request.getParameter("destination"); %>` and `<% String products[]= request.getParameterValues("product"); %>` didn't received any data.

When using the standard form, both can display result. This code is written in same page(JSP).

--The first coding cannot be changed because it was the assignment and need to solve it.--

Comment: looking into abstract details your requirement looks like you can use `AJAX` call

Comment: `AJAX` call??? Do you know any website that can tell me that??? Better from video tutorial..

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Answer (score 0):

Add a form tag in your code like

```
<form name="form1" method="POST">
   <table>

   <!-- Your code ->

    <a  id="search" name="search" class="button orange small" style="cursor:pointer" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.form1.submit();">SEARCH</a>

   </table>
</form>
```

**Things to remember**

- Form tag: method(POST), Name of form(form1)
- Method called on onclick of a tag

Comment: umm.. but didn't I said that the first coding cannot be altered.. Let just say that the first coding is the question.. And I need to solve it

Comment: The only difference is form tag and onclick method. If you want to submit a page then there must be a form to submit.